# PrimeFaces selectOneMenu not disabling

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have a selectOneMenu and trying to disable on page load. I have a couple other inputText elements that do become disabled when the onLoad is triggered. When searching the web I did find a couple other questions around this topic but no answers. Anyone know if this is a known issue or there is a work around to get the selectOneMenu to become disabled/enabled?

Comment: show your code , basically you need to use the `disabled="#{myBean.myCondition}"` ....

Comment: I want to be able to disabled/enabled on a jquery call...here is my code:

Comment: $j(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('question')).attr('disabled',true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INMO no way you can do it in such a way that you described (`$j(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('question')).attr('disabled',true);`) look into what its being rendered.... probably some kinda complex table...

If you need to disable it on page load just use the `disabled` attribute... if you need to disable from client side later on use the [primeface blockUI](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/blockUI.jsf)